# SSL setup on AWS Elasticbeanstalk single instance - No Load Balancer

Tags: python, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django/python based web application that I have been deploying to AWS for the past year. Now we need to get SSL setup so our users can sign up and make payments online.

I've integrated the Stripe checkout js and now I am trying to get a **self signed** SSL certificate, **FOR TESTING**, to run on my DEV AWS EB instance.

I went through the AWS documentation here 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html#CreateSSLConfig.SingleInstance

AND, for the config file:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSLPython.SingleInstance.html

Now when I deploy to my AWS instance, I am getting the following errors:

```
2015-09-29 23:07:48 UTC-0400    ERROR   [Instance: *****] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .
2015-09-29 23:07:47 UTC-0400    ERROR   Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.py failed with returncode 1
```

I am not sure what is going on or how to go about debugging these errors.

Here is my config file:

---

```
  Resources: 
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
  Properties: 
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    FromPort: 443
    GroupId: 
      Ref: AWSEBSecurityGroup
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 443
  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
  files: 
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: 
  content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver
        Redirect permanent / https://myserver
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myserver


        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"

        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py

        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
          home=/opt/python/current/app
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl
      </VirtualHost>
  group: root
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt: 
  content: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n\
      ********=\n\
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----\n\
      \x20\n"
  group: root
  mode: "000400"
  owner: root
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key: 
  content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      *******
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  group: root
  mode: "000400"
  owner: root
  packages: 
  yum: 
  mod24_ssl: []
```

I created my private key, certificate key and self signed certificate using OpenSSL when I SSH'ed into the EC2 instance under the ec2-user. In some cases, I've seen people have these files in `/var/www/html/.` I have the files in the home directory, would that cause a problem?

Any ideas of how to diagnose this or is there a better approach to setting up SSL on a single EB instance?

Thank you.

Comment: what uses is web server running under? does it have access to the cert files? 400 root on the server.key with another user means you will not be able to read the file.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out Mircea. We are using Amazon Linux image of the server. Not sure how to test if it has access to the cert files? I do add the content to the config file above, instead of the *****.

Comment: what user is web server running under?

Comment: To create the certificate, I ssh into the EC2 instance using ec2-user. It seems like I need to create or update an IAM user, not sure I know how to do that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I did not. I ended up setting up my EC2 instance with a load balancer and then providing the inbound rule the SSL certificate.